# Connect to existing hsqldb instance in IDE

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, hsqldb

I am learning Spring Boot using open-source projects and have stumbled upon their demo project — [PetClinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic). It has two possible databases configured: MySQL & HSQLDB, it uses the latter by default.
So I was able to launch the project look at it on `localhost` and can see that the DB (HSQLDB) is being populated but I was unable to set up a connection through the Intellij IDEA because the project does not specify the path that allows to see the contents of this in-memory DB.

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone please tell me, what am I missing in the process of establishing the connection to HSQLDB here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't connect to an in-memory instance of HSQLDB from another process.

> The main drawback [of in-memory mode] is that it is not possible by default to connect to
>   the database from outside your application. As a result you cannot
>   check the contents of the database with external tools such as
>   Database Manager while your application is running.

If you want to do this, you need to run HSQL as a server.  More details about how to run it in server mode [can be found here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_server_modes).